# how do I tell sympy that a variable is known?

Tags: sympy, linear-algebra

I am trying to solve a large system of linear equations with 32 unknown variables and 4 known variables und 34 equations using sympy.

known variables: `e, j, o, t`
unknown variables: `a, b, c, d, f, g, h,  i, j, k, l, m, n, o,  p, q, r, s, t, u, v,  w, x, y, z, a_a, b_b, c_c, e_e, t_t, f_f,  m_m, p_p, s_s, o_o`

I am looking for expressions for `u, v, w, y, z, c_c` but only depending on the known variables.

How can I tell sypmy that `e, j, o, t` are known?

I tryed solving my problem like this:

```
import sympy as sp

a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k, l, m, n, o, p, q, r, s, t, u, v, w, x, y, z = sp.symbols(
    'a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z')
a_a, b_b, c_c, e_e, t_t, f_f, m_m, p_p, s_s, o_o = sp.symbols(
    'a_a b_b c_c e_e t_t f_f m_m p_p s_s o_o')

eq1 = sp.Eq(a+b+c+d, e)
eq2 = sp.Eq(f+g+h+i, j)
eq3 = sp.Eq(k+l+m+n, o)
eq4 = sp.Eq(p+q+r+s, t)
eq5 = sp.Eq(a+f+k+p, 1)
eq6 = sp.Eq(b+g+l+q, 1)
eq7 = sp.Eq(c+h+m+r, 1)
eq8 = sp.Eq(d+i+n+s, 1)
eq9 = sp.Eq(1/m_m, a)
eq10 = sp.Eq(x/m_m, f)
eq11 = sp.Eq(a_a/m_m, k)
eq12 = sp.Eq(e_e/m_m, p)
eq13 = sp.Eq(u/p_p, b)
eq14 = sp.Eq(1/p_p, g)
eq15 = sp.Eq(b_b/p_p, l)
eq16 = sp.Eq(t_t/p_p, q)
eq17 = sp.Eq(v/s_s, l)
eq18 = sp.Eq(y/s_s, h)
eq19 = sp.Eq(1/s_s, m)
eq20 = sp.Eq(f_f/s_s, r)
eq21 = sp.Eq(w/o_o, d)
eq22 = sp.Eq(z/o_o, i)
eq23 = sp.Eq(c_c/o_o, n)
eq24 = sp.Eq(1/o_o, s)
eq25 = sp.Eq(x, 1/u)
eq26 = sp.Eq(a_a, 1/v)
eq27 = sp.Eq(e_e, 1/w)
eq28 = sp.Eq(b_b, 1/y)
eq29 = sp.Eq(t_t, 1/z)
eq30 = sp.Eq(f_f, 1/c_c)
eq31 = sp.Eq(1+x+a_a+e_e, m_m)
eq32 = sp.Eq(u+1+b_b+t_t, p_p)
eq33 = sp.Eq(v+y+1+f_f, s_s)
eq34 = sp.Eq(w+z+c_c+1, o_o)

solution = sp.solve((eq1, eq2, eq3, eq4, eq5, eq6,
                    eq7, eq8, eq9, eq10, eq11, eq12,
                    eq13, eq14, eq15, eq16, eq17, eq18,
                    eq19, eq20, eq21, eq22, eq23, eq24,
                    eq25, eq26, eq27, eq28, eq29, eq30,
                    eq31, eq32, eq33, eq34
                     ), u, v, w, y, z, c_c)

print(solution)
```

The print function gives me an empty list:

```
[]
```

I expected the syntax to be correct, since I don't get any errors, but I did not find a way to tell sympy that `e, j, o, t` are known and that I want the solution to be dependend of the known variables `e, j, o, t` only.

Comment: You've listed e as both known and unknown. In any case you need to pass all unknown symbols to `solve` (not just the ones that you want to know). Any symbols not passed are considered to be known.

Comment: What's wrong with the `solution` (that you printed - but didn't show)?

Comment: @hpaulj sorry for not mentioning and thank you for addressing. I have edited the post and also inserted the feedback of @OscarBenjamin. I added all unknown variables to the `solve`  function and left out those who are known. The solution gives me an empty list. The documention says that this means, that there is no solution for this problem. I would have expected that there is an solution, but am not sure of it. Would you say, that the syntax and the generell way of the solution make sense now? In that case I would accept that there is no solution. Thank you either way!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you eliminate all single-letter variables (except for e,j,o,t) you end up with 10 nonlinear equations in 11 unknowns and the constraint `e + j + o + t = 4` as the 11 equation. So it seems you would need an additional relationship to solve this system of equations. I replaced `a_a` with `A`, etc..., and am keeping only the numerators of your expressions and this is what I get:

```py
[e + j + o + t - 4, 
E*O*P*S + F*M*O*P - M*O*P*S*t + M*O*S*T + M*P*S, 
O*P*S*(-B**2*M*O*S - B*C*M*P*S + B*E*O*P*S + B*M*O*P*S*o - B*M*O*P - B*M*O*S*T - B*M*O*S + B*O*P*S + C*M*P**2*S - C*M*P*S*T - C*M*P*S - E*O*P**2*S + E*O*P*S*T + E*O*P*S - M*O*P**2*S*o + M*O*P**2*S + M*O*P**2 + M*O*P*S*T*o - M*O*P*S*T + M*O*P*S*o - M*O*P*S - M*O*P*T - M*O*P - O*P**2*S + O*P*S*T), 
S*(-B**2*M*O*S - B*C*M*P*S + B*M*O*P*S*o - B*M*O*P - O*P**2), 
-B**2*E*M*O*S - B*E*F*M*O*P - B*E*M*O*P*S*e + 2*B*E*M*O*P*S - B*E*M*O*P - B*E*M*O*S*T - B*E*M*O*S + B*E*O*P*S + B*M*P*S - E*M*O*P, O*P*S*(-C*E*M*P*S*T + E**2*O*P*S*T + E*F*M*O*P*T + E*M*O*P*S*T*e + E*M*O*P*S*T*j + E*M*O*P*S*T*o - 3*E*M*O*P*S*T + E*M*O*S*T**2 - E*M*P*S - M*P*S*T), 
C*F - 1, 
-S*(E*M*O*P*e - E*M*O*P + E*M*O*T + E*M*O - E*O*P - M*P), 
O*P*S*(E*O*P*S + F*M*O*P + M*O*P*S*e + M*O*P*S*j + M*O*P*S*o - 4*M*O*P*S + M*O*S*T + M*P*S)]
```

Comment: thank you for your afford!
That is very interesting, because there is another equation that I did not put into my list of equations because I thought it doesn't help me with solving my problem. The equation is: `e + j + o + t = 1`
Do you think I mixed something up with the other equations?

Comment: The equations you gave already imply that `e+j+o+t=4` so if you want them to equal 1 there is something wrong with your equations.

Comment: Ok, in that case I'd go back to the equations, but since I worked around the problem and my solution is not related, to the post anymore, there won't be any updates. Thank you to everyone for helping me!